# how to join the value of 3 variables and add them to a hidden field

Tags: javascript

I have 3 variables and I was wondering how to join their values and add them to a hidden field,

```
   document.getElementById('my-item-name').value = meat.join("\t");
```

it works for 1 but when I add the other variable it doesn't work.

```
  document.getElementById('my-item-name').value = meat.join("\t").veg.join("\t").sause.join("\t");
```

the variables are meat, veg, and sauce.

thanks

Answer (score 4):

I think you are trying to concatenate the variables:

```
document.getElementById('my-item-name').value = meat + "\t" + veg + "\t" +
                                                sause + "\t";
```

The [join function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) is applied to Arrays, you could use it also:

```
document.getElementById('my-item-name').value = [meat,veg,sause].join('\t');
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the '+' operator:

```
document.getElementById('my-item-name').value = meat + "\t" + veg + "\t" + sause;
```

Answer (score 0):

document.getElementById('my-item-name').value = meat + "\t" + veg + "\t" + sause + "\t";